# string comparison against factors in Stata

Tags: comparison, stata

Suppose I have a [factor variable](http://www.stata.com/features/overview/factor-variables/) with labels "a" "b" and "c" and want to see which observations have a label of "b". Stata refuses to parse

```
gen isb = myfactor == "b"
```

Sure, there is literally a "type mismatch", since my factor is encoded as an integer and so cannot be compared to the string "b". However, it wouldn't kill Stata to (i) perform the obvious parse or (ii) provide a translator function so I can write the comparison as `label(myfactor) == "b"`. Using `decode` to (re)create a string variable defeats the purpose of encoding, which is to save space and make computations more efficient, right?

---

I hadn't really expected the comparison above to work, but I at least figured there would be a one- or two-line approach. Here is what I have found so far. There is a nice macro ("extended") function that maps the other way (from an integer to a label, seen below as `local labi: label ...`). Here's the solution using it:

```
// sample data 

clear
input str5 mystr int mynum
a 5
b 5
b 6
c 4
end

encode mystr, gen(myfactor)

// first, how many groups are there?

by myfactor, sort: gen ng = _n == 1
replace ng = sum(ng)
scalar ng = ng[_N]
drop ng

// now, which code corresponds to "b"?

forvalues i = 1/`=ng'{
    local labi: label myfactor `i'
    if "b" == "`labi'" {
        scalar bcode = `i'
        break
    }
}

di bcode
```

The second step is what irks me, but I'm sure there's a also faster, more idiomatic way of performing the first step. Can I grab the length of the label vector, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

gen isdom = 1 if foreign == "Domestic":`:value label foreign'

list foreign isdom in 1/60
```

This creates a variable called `isdom` and it will equal 1 if `foreigns`'s value label is equal to "Domestic". It uses an *extended macro function*.

From **[U] 18.3.8** Macro expressions:

> Also, typing
>
> ```
> command that makes reference to `:extended macro function'
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> local macroname : extended macro function
> command that makes reference to `macroname'
> ```

This explains one of the two `:` in the offered syntax. The other can be explained by

> ... to specify value labels directly in an expression, rather than through
>   the underlying numeric value ... You specify the label in double quotes
>   (""), followed by a colon (:), followed by the name of the value
>   label.

The quote is from *Stata tip 14: Using value labels in expressions*, by Kenneth Higbee, The Stata Journal (2004). Freely available at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0009

### Edit

On computing the number of distinct observations, another way is:

```
by myfactor, sort: gen ng = _n == 1
count if ng
scalar sc_ng = r(N)

display sc_ng
```

But yours is fine. In fact, it is documented here: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/number-of-distinct-observations/, along with more methods and comments.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Going to try this out when I get back to work & Stata on Monday. Do you happen to know a faster way of finding the number of labels than the approach I used in my "First, how many groups are there?" step?

Comment: Search for a program -distinct- and the associated paper in the *Stata Journal*.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out fine. It might be useful to explain what ``:value label foreign'` is doing here, as the double colon is quite confusing (even having read the "extended macro" documentation).

Comment: I've added some references that should help.