# Stata factor value from label

Tags: stata

I would like to look up a value/code associated with a label, and store that value in a scalar or local macro. While the information I want is stored in the definition of the label vector, apparently I need to go through some contortions to get it.

Extending Roberto Ferrer's [answer to my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25942520/1191259), I came up with this approach:

```
// sample data 

clear
input str5 mystr int mynum
a 5
b 5
b 6
c 4
end

encode mystr, gen(myfactor)

// get code for "b"

gen tmp = 0
replace tmp = myfactor if myfactor == "b":myfactor
sort tmp
scalar bcode = tmp[_N]
```

This seems woefully inefficient in terms of data manipulation and code maintenance, especially considering how the information I want is already saved (and viewable with `label list`).

Comment: Maybe the idea is that reverse lookup does not make sense for factor variables because one might want to have multiple labels map to the same code/value? If so, I wonder what sort of statistical operations Stata's designers have in mind for such strange, obfuscated variables...?

Comment: You can probably work something out with `uselabel, clear var` (that clears the current dataset and creates a new one). See the corresponding help file. There might be user-written alternatives. Use `search`.

Comment: Check `labellist` at http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457275.html. It should also be available with `ssc describe labellist`, but I have limited internet access so I can't be sure. Use the stored results it produces. See `help stored results`.

Comment: There is indeed no rule that a given string is attached as value label to at most one numeric value, even for a given variable. So, look-up is not guaranteed unique. Your use of the term "variables" here is unclear. In Stata, only data columns are variables; everything else has some other name.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for clarifying. Yes, I did mean a column variable, not a programming (?) variable. I can see no reason to allow the same label to be attached to multiple values for a column variable. Such labeling would only obfuscate the underlying data, which is reason enough to disallow it (on top of the benefit that would be gained -- of enabling label lookup both ways). Anyway, I'm glad someone with more Stata skills than me decided to make a package (`labellist`) that will allow me to work without going insane.

Comment: I can easily think of situations in which the same value label for different values makes sense. It's not common, but it's not impossible or absurd. I've wanted to label dates on a graph by which party was in power, say "Dem" and "Rep" for U.S. data. A similar issue is common with spatial data. There is no obfuscation there, any more than squaring positive and negative values is wrong because different values have the same square root or a `recode` in Stata is obfuscatory if it's not uniquely reversible.

Comment: In all those cases, I would use a separate variable to store the information. I can't swear to its effectiveness for graphing in Stata, but it works for all other purposes with nested/hierarchical (e.g., spatial) data and irreversible transformations (like squaring). To my mind, labels seem uniquely suited to categorical variables (or "factors"), used for `i.varname` in regression commands; and their usefulness is greatly diminished by the lack of a one-to-one mapping. I think Stata doesn't take this stance simply because labels existed before Stata 11, while factors did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `labellist`, from SSC. Download using `ssc install labellist`.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input str5 mystr
"good"
"bad"
"bad"
"regular"
end

encode mystr, gen(myfactor)

*----- what you want -----

labellist

local faclab = r(myfactor_labels)
local facval = r(myfactor_values)

// get # for "good"
local i : list posof "good" in faclab
local j : word `i' of `facval'

display "`j'"
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was seeking! I'm curious: do you generally find packages with `search`? `search label lookup` gave me nothing, while `search label` gave me too much.

Comment: Yes, `search` can give many results but it is generally successfull in showing relevant options. Summaries allow quick reads.